# Moving arguments and \protect: coming to grips with the definitions

Tags: sourcecode, protected-macro

I'm trying to understand the precise semantics of `\protect` as described in the beginning of section 11.4 *Robust commands and protect* of the [`source2e`](https://texdoc.net/pkdg/source2e) document, the annotated source code of the LaTeX2e format, on pp. 42-43 (I have substituted numbers below for bullet points in source2e):

> [...] there are (at least) three different occasions when these commands [i.e. `LaTeX` commands --Evan Aad] are not safe. These are called 'moving arguments' by `LaTeX`, and consist of:
>
> 1. writing information to a file, such as indexes or tables of contents.
> 2. writing information to the screen.
> 3. inside an `\edef`, `\message`, `\mark`, or other command which evaluates its argument fully.
>
> The method `LaTeX` uses for making fragile commands robust is to
>   precede them with `\protect`. This can have one of five possible
>   values:
>
> 1. `\relax`, for normal typesetting. So `\protect\foo` will execute `\foo`.
> 2. `\string`, for writing to the screen. So `\protect\foo` will write `\foo`.
> 3. `\noexpand`, for writing to a file. So `\protect\foo` will write `\foo` followed by a space.
> 4. `\@unexpandable@protect`, for writing a moving argument to a file. So `\protect\foo` will write `\protect\foo` followed by a space. This
>      value is also used inside `\edef`s, `\mark`s and other commands which
>      evaluate their arguments fully.
> 5. `\@unexpandable@noexpand`, for performing a deferred write inside an `\edef`. So `\protect\foo` will write `\foo` followed by a space.
>      If you want `\protect\foo` to be written, you should use
>      `\@unexpandable@protect`. (Removed as never used.)

I struggle with the following issues.

1. Item 4: The term 'moving argument' is used in a way that is inconsistent with the way it was defined before. In the opening paragraph it was defined as one of three occasions when the use of commands is risky, whereas in item 4 it designates a chunk of the input that is written to a file. So what exactly is a *moving argument*?
2. Item 4: There's a mismatch between items 3 and 4: Item 3 says 'for writing to a file' and item 4 says 'for writing a moving argument to a file'. So the condition expressed in item 3 subsumes the one expressed in item 4, yet the actions specified in each case are different. How is it possible?
3. Item 5: What's a 'deferred write'?
4. Item 5: At the end of the item there's a comment that reads 'Removed as never used.` What does it mean?

---

This question is related to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4736/21685).

Comment: Re. 3.  There is a difference between \write, \immediate\write and \protected@write.  \protected@write does not write until the code is shipped, even if it is inside a savebox.  It also prevents \thepage from being expanded immediately.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A 'moving' argument is where the argument to some LaTeX command will be 'moved around', either by writing it to a file, writing it to a message or by otherwise fully-expanding it. The confusion likely occurs because these have some overlap, and because two cases may apply simultaneously. In particular, we sometimes need to write material to file which *itself* will constitute a moving context when read back, which is why there is a difference between 'write to a file' and 'write a moving argument to a file'. We also may need to 'force' expansion for stuff which will later be expanded again: the 'deferred write' business.

The 'classical' example of a moving argument is the mandatory value which goes with a sectioning command:

```
\section{This-is-a-moving-argument~\cite{Lamport}}
```

I've also deliberately included a couple of items that need handling properly, `~` and `\cite`. Both have 'robust' internals:

- `~` => `\nobreakspace {}` => `\protect \nobreakspace[space]`
- `\cite` => `\protect\cite[space]`

(Those `[space]` markers are part of the token names, so are important.)

Let's see what happens in various cases. The first is easy: typesetting the section heading. Here, `\protect` is `\relax` and does nothing, and we execute `\nobreakspace[space]` or `\cite[space]`, respectively.

To get the second case we need to create a message. I'll use two to illustrate a subtle point:

```
\PackageWarning{foo}{\cite seen}
\PackageWarning{foo}{\protect\cite seen}
```

would yield

```
Package foo Warning: \cite seen on input line ...
Package foo Warning: \citeseen on input line ...
```

Notice the spacing difference. Applying `\tracingall` you'll see it happens as in the first case we get `\cite` expanding to `\protect\cite[space]`, and it's the latter that `\protect` as `\string` is applied to. In the second line, we directly apply `\protect` (`\string`) to `\cite`, so there is no space. (Remember that the 'space' after `\cite` is dropped by TeX at a low level.)

For the third case, we could again 'force the issue' by writing to a file

```
\makeatletter
\newwrite\mywrite
\immediate\openout\mywrite=\jobname.tmp
\protected@write\mywrite{}{\cite{}}
Foo\newpage % See later!
```

will yield

```
\cite  {}
```

where there are *two* spaces in the file: that's because we are exploring case 3. Applying `\noexpand` to `\cite[space]` inserts an *additional* space after the name. (Crucially, those spaces are ignored when reading back: a central part of this 'trick'.)

Before we move to case 4, we need to know something about how `\write` works and what a 'deferred write' is. The TeX `\write` primitive stores its argument for writing during page shipout: that is necessary to know page numbers and similar.  Expansion happens *at the point of writing to the file*. This means that some content may have changed: not ideal. The LaTeX `\protected@write` macro works by expanding its argument with a few exceptions, then waiting for the shipout to deal with those 'left overs', which includes page number:

```
\long\def \protected@write#1#2#3{%
      \begingroup
       \let\thepage\relax
       #2%
       \let\protect\@unexpandable@protect
       \edef\reserved@a{\write#1{#3}}%
       \reserved@a
      \endgroup
      \if@nobreak\ifvmode\nobreak\fi\fi
}
```

That takes us back to case four and the `\section` example. For writing TOC data, this will end up calling

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect \contentsline {section}
  {\ifnum 1>\c@secnumdepth \else \protect \numberline {\csname thesection\endcsname }\fi This-is-a-moving-argument~\cite {Lamport}}
  {\thepage }}
```

which is then passed to `\protected@write`.  The 'payload' gets passed to the `\edef`, and we get `\reserved@a` defined as

```
\write \@auxout {\@writefile{toc}{\protect \contentsline {section
}{\protect \numberline {1}This-is-a-moving-argument\protect \nobreakspace  {}\protect \cite  {Lamport}}{\thepage }}}
```

because `\protect` was `\@unexpandable@protect`. That now goes forward to the 'raw' `\write`, which will do another exhaustive expansion with `\protect` as `\noexpand`, and the content we want will transfer to the `.aux` file, including the expanded page number.

Case five, as noted, is not used so is removed!

---

Worth noting is that all of this cleverness predates e-TeX: today one can make macros `\protected` and they don't expand inside a `\write` or `\edef`, and life is a lot easier.

Comment: The `[space]` in `\cite[space]` and `\nobreakspace[space]` isn't literal, right? It is a meta term that you used to indicating a single space character (input code point 32), rather than the 7 character string `[`-`s`-`p`-`a`-`c`-`e`-`]`, right?

Comment: @EvanAad Yes, that's why I wrote it in square brackets :) I should probably hunt about for a 'printable space' character ...

Comment: Thanks. What's `\protected@write`?

Comment: @EvanAad I've included the definition in my answer: it's a LaTeX wrapper around `\write` which applies the 'protect' mechanism.

Comment: Oops, sorry. I stopped reading when I got to this unknown command after not seeing it defined in the subsequent paragraph. Talk about tunnel vision... By the way, why can't I replace this code segment with the following: `\documentclass{article} \begin{document}\openout0=myfile \immediate\write0{\cite.} \closeout0 \end{document}`. This yields an error, and I don't understand why. I expect it to produce the output `\cite[space][space].`.

Comment: @EvanAad If you use a 'raw' `\write` then the 'protect' mechanism doesn't operate (it needs set up), and `\protect` has the value `\relax` (typesetting). So `\cite[space]` is just expanded. We then are back with the starting issue: you can't perform assignments inside an expansion context. To use the LaTeX2e mechanism you _have_ to go _via_ the defined interfaces, you can't use a 'raw' `\write` or `\edef` (_etc._). See also my point about e-TeX: that's engine-level so can be used inside a 'raw'  `\write` (try `\protected\edef\cite{\unexpanded\expandafter{\cite}}`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61206/discussion-between-evan-aad-and-joseph-wright).