# Argument of \@tempf has an extra }. Runaway argument?

Tags: errors, captions

In one of my figures I have the following caption, that calls the `\citeasnoun` command. Unfortunately that leads to a warning/error and I am not sure why.

The latex code that I'm using:

```
\caption{A visual representation of our recurrent neural network, heavily influenced by \citeasnoun{some_author}.}
```

And the error:

```
Argument of \@tempf has an extra }. Runaway argument?
```

Comment: Try \protect\citeasnoun.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks, that works. Could you perhaps post it as an answer and also elaborate on how and why this works?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4747/2388 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/377057/2388